# Matplotlib: plotting data labels on data connected to parasite axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a variation on the 'how to I plot data labels' question I've seen a few places on SO.  But, I've never seen it done on a parasite axis.

Basically, I want data labels above each point for the time series (in green) connected to the parasite (right) vertical axis.

This is what I have currently:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
plotorder=[239, 133, 94, 42, 31, 27, 49, 99, 172, 292, 397, 439, 450, 391, 429, 374, 382, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
lastyearorders=[119, 78, 49, 29, 14, 12, 30, 46, 108, 154, 194, 224, 181, 199, 213, 186, 167, 152, 135, 115, 99, 106, 97, 90]
difference=[100.8, 70.5, 91.8, 44.8, 121.4, 125.0, 63.3, 115.2, 59.3, 89.6, 104.6, 96.0, 148.6, 96.5, 101.4, 101.1, 128.7, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
ordersMax=max(plotorder+lastyearorders)
growthMax=max(difference)

host = host_subplot(111)

par = host.twinx()
host.set_xlabel("Hour")
host.set_ylabel("Orders")
par.set_ylabel("% Growth")
host.set_xlim(0,24)
host.set_ylim(0,ordersMax*1.1)
par.set_ylim(0,growthMax*2)
p1, = host.plot(times, plotorder, linewidth=2, marker='o', color='r', label="Today's Orders")
p1, = host.plot(times, lastyearorders, linewidth=2, color='b', label="LY Orders")
p2, = par.plot(times, difference, marker='s', color='green', label="% Growth")
leg = plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I've tried using both `par.plot_text(times[1], difference[1], difference[1])` and `par.annotate()`, but both threw errors that say `AttributeError: 'AxesParasite' object has no attribute 'plot_text'`

This is what I currently have:

[image: chart1]

I want something like this (from Excel):

[image: CHART 2]

Comment: What error did `par.annotate` throw? You should be able to iterate through something like `for t, d in zip(times, differences): par.annotate('{}'.format(d), xy = (t, d), ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (x,y) in zip(times, difference):
    if y:
         par.annotate("{0}%".format(y), xy=(x, y+10))
```

This seems to work for me, what did you try for annotate?

Comment: It's working for me now too (from my home computer).  Let me double-check with my work computer next week, but in the meantime, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: yes, it works now.  I'll update my question with the par.annotate error-- it was just an issue with my understanding of the function.